# How to Set Default language in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-localization

I'm using laravel locale, How to set default language.
my app.php, that is not working.

```
'locale' => 'my',    
'timezone' => 'Asia/Rangoon',
'fallback_locale' => 'my',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set locale as you showed above, but to see translated texts, you should create directory with translated files into `resources/lang/my` directory. You can use 3rd party package https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang/tree/master/src with translated languages (I don't see here `my`).